# Query param not working on refresh or manual load

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a component `pages/user/[username].js` for displaying a user's profile page.

When on the page I use `let { username } = router.query` to get the username from the query params, this works no problem when redirected from somewhere on the site using `` router.push(`/user/${username}`) ``.

However, If I refresh the page or manually load `localhost:3000/user/someusername` the router.query object is empty and I cannot retrieve the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a normal behavior because your page is [statically optimized](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works)

> During prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we do not have query information to provide during this phase. After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

> To be able to distinguish if the query is fully updated and ready for use, you can leverage the isReady field on next/router.

You have to use `router.isReady` in a `useEffect`, something like the code below:

```
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!router.isReady) return;

    // codes using router.query

}, [router.isReady]);
```